# align two words in a select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I have the select below:

```
<select name="mySelect">
   <option value="1">hello [test]</option>
   <option value="2">hello2 [test2]</option>
   <option value="3">hello33 [test33]</option>
   <option value="4">hel [hel]</option>
</select>
```

How can I align the text inside the options to appear like this:

```
hello____[test]

hello2___[test2]

hello33__[test33]

hel_____ [hel]
```

I tried adding spaces with JavaScript but they are not visible. ( _ is space char above)

Comment: You could use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Also the font should be monospaced. Set this in your css.

Comment: again with &nbsp they are not alligned properly... although the whitespace is added.

Comment: So `hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[test]` doesn't work properly? A screenshot or fiddle would be nice.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbk600a0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to firstly set your `select` element to use a monospace font (that is a font whose characters all have the same width), then to pad out your element with the `&nbsp;` [character entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```css
select {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="1">hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[test]</option>
  <option value="2">hello2&nbsp;&nbsp;[test2]</option>
  <option value="3">hello33&nbsp;[test33]</option>
  <option value="4">hel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[hel]</option>
</select>
```

As you can see this does make your markup quite ugly. It also forces you to use a font which probably isn't used site-wide and may be undesirable. I believe this is the only way you can accurately achieve this though, without replacing your `select` element completely with some JavaScript-controlled element strucutre.

---

Depending on what your `hello` or `[test]` texts are supposed to represent, the `optgroup` element may be what you're looking for:

```html
<select name="mySelect">
  <optgroup label="[test]">
      <option value="1">hello</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="[test2]">
    <option value="2">hello2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="[test33]">
    <option value="3">hello33</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="[hel]">
    <option value="4">hel</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: could i somehow preserve the font i currently use? is there a solution by adding any span and align left and right?

Comment: @sstauross not that I'm aware of, unless the font you currently use is monospace itself. You can't add HTML tags within `option` elements. As I wrote at the end of my answer, the only other option I can think of would be to replace the `select` element with a JavaScript-controlled structure which appears to do the same thing - although this would probably land you in a lot of issues with cross-browser and mobile device compatibility.