# How do I align two words in Select Option in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: I want to align both name and account number]

As you can see in the image, how can I set different spacing for each Option tag in a Select tag and align them properly. Those values are being retrieved dynamically from the database, so I cannot estimate the gaps between Name and Account Number to use this `&nbsp;`

This is the code for an option which is enclosed in a for loop to get the values:

```
<option value=<%= cus.getId()%>,<%= cus.getName()%>,<%= cus.getEmail()%>,<%= cus.getBalance()%> >
    Name = <%= cus.getName()%> Account Number = <%= cus.getId()%>
</option>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: ```<option value=<%= cus.getId()%>,<%= cus.getName()%>,<%= cus.getEmail()%>,<%= cus.getBalance()%> >
Name = <%= cus.getName()%> Account Number = <%= cus.getId()%> </option>``` This is the option which is enclosed in a for loop which get the values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26358408/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most fancy solution is to have a javascript based custom component, where basically everything is possible.

However, you can get a long way like this. No Javascript required:

1. Simplest quick-and-dirty solution:
   Switch account number and name.

[image]

2. You can set the font to monospace.
   [image]

```html
<html>
    <style>
        select,
        option{font-family:monospace};
    </style>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>Account Number=1000055    Name=X</option>
            <option>Account Number=1000056    Name=Anjali</option>
            <option>Account Number=1000057    Name=Keerthy </option>            
            <option>Account Number=1000058    Name=Looooooooooong name</option>
        </select>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a great work around. Idk how did this slip from my mind. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use javascript to achieve what you want. Also, you have to use any monospace font for your select tag to keep the alignment correct.

Here is an example:

```css
select,
option {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script>
  const maxLength = 15;

  function processInfo(name, accountNumber) {
    var output = "Name = " + name;

    for (var i = 0; i < maxLength - name.length; i++) {
      output += "&nbsp;";
    }
    output += "Account Number = ";
    output += accountNumber;

    return output;
  }
</script>

<select>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Mahesh", "10000052"));
    </script>
  </option>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Pawan", "10000053"));
    </script>
  </option>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Tarak", "10000054"));
    </script>
  </option>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Arjun", "10000055"));
    </script>
  </option>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Anjali", "10000056"));
    </script>
  </option>
  <option>
    <script>
      document.write(processInfo("Keerthy", "10000057"));
    </script>
  </option>
</select>
```

Above example is self-explaining. A maximum fixed length size is set initially. And, then find out the actual length of the provided name and add required numbers of space-character (`&nbsp;`) dynamically after the name, which can be found by subtracting actual length of the input name from the max length.